# How to deal with many jQuery 'on' click events in native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, document

As I move more an more into web apps and into using asynchronous content loading. I end up with many many $(document).on('click') event listeners.

I would like to write this in plain JavaScript and am unsure the best way to do this. The following is what I want to get away from as it feels icky.

```
var doc = $(document);

doc.on('click', 'someElement1', function(){});
doc.on('click', 'someElement2', function(){});
doc.on('click', 'someElement3', function(){});
doc.on('click', 'someElement4', function(){});
doc.on('click', 'someElement5', function(){});
```

Every click has something different to do and because of the way I componentise everything and write functions that could be used in many places, it feels like using document all the time as opposed to a parent element is a safer approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about `event.target` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre — event.target gives you the actual element clicked on, jQuery delegated events match the element the selector matches and all of its descendants.

Comment: If anyone has time, would you be able to put together a best practice version of the above without using jQuery?

Comment: @matt3224 I can suggest a jquery version solution using just one .on event listner with as many if conditions to check which button/div was clicked and then you can write your function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

@shivgre I mean i can take a guess at that, perhaps something like:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {

    if (e.target === $('someElement1')[0]) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }

    if (e.target === $('someElement2')[0]) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }

    if (e.target === $('someElement3')[0]) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }

    if (e.target === $('someElement4')[0]) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }

    if (e.target === $('someElement5')[0]) {
        /* do some stuff */
    }

});
```

I mean maybe im overthinking it as the jQuery free solution wouldn't be much different. The key reason im doing `$(document).on('click');` is because theres heavy use of ajax to load content. Is there any way around this?

It just feels overkill to trigger all document click events every time theres a click on the page. Any thoughts on tackling this?